# Regex that matches anything but ignores anything that starts with an @ sign

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

For example, if I have something like this:

```
@username test
```

I want it to ignore `@username` if it starts with an at sign but include anything else so when I run the code I want only `test` to show.

Comment: Use `re.sub()` to replace a word that begins with `@` with an empty string.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex needed here:

```
string = "@username test"

words = " ".join([word for word in string.split() if not word.startswith('@')])
print(words)
# test
```